# Construct an integral operator and show that this operator is a contraction on $(C[0, T], ρ)$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, integral-equations, initial-value-problems, contraction-operator

Let $T > 0$ and $L ≥ 0$. Consider $C[0, T]$, the space of all continuous real
valued functions on $[0, T]$, with the metric $ρ$ defined by
$ρ(x, y) = \sup\limits_{
(0≤t≤T)}
e
^{−Lt}|x(t) − y(t)|$.

Consider the initial value problem

$
x'
(t) = f(t, x(t))$ for $t > 0,$
$x(0) = x_0.$

where f : $\Bbb R × \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ is continuous and globally Lipschitz continuous with
respect to x, i.e, there exists $L ≥ 0$ such that
$|f(t, x) − f(t, y)| ≤ L|x − y|$ for all $t, x, y ∈ \Bbb R.$

Construct an integral operator and show that this operator is a contraction on $(C[0, T], ρ)$. Hence deduce
that the initial value problem has a unique solution in $C^
1
[0, T].$

**To use the contraction mapping theorem, I have managed to prove that $(C[0, T], ρ)$ is a completes metric space. But I really don't know how to construct a suitable integral operator.**

Comment: If $\varphi$ is a solution to the initial value problem, then $$\varphi(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t \varphi'(s)\,ds.$$ What was $\varphi'(s)$ again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_f$ denote the Lipschitz constant of $f$ and choose $L := 2L_f$ in the definition of $\rho$.
Define the standard Picard operator
$$
Tx (t) := x_0 + \int_0^t f(s, x(s))\, ds,
\qquad x\in C[0,T].
$$
Then it holds
$$
(*) \qquad \rho(Tx, Ty) \leq \frac{1}{2} \rho(x,y),
\qquad \forall x,y\in C[0,T].
$$
Namely, let $x,y\in C[0,T]$. By the very definition of $\rho$ we have that
$$
|x(s) - y(s)| \leq \rho(x,y)\, e^{2 L_f s}, \quad \forall s\in [0,T].
$$
Since 
$$
\int_0^t e^{2 L_f s}\, ds = \frac{1}{2 L_f} (e^{2 L_f t} - 1) <\frac{1}{2 L_f} e^{2 L_f t},
$$
we get
$$
|Tx(t) - Ty(t)| \leq \int_0^t L_f |x(s) - y(s)|\, ds
\leq \int_0^t L_f \rho(x,y)\, e^{2L_f s}\, ds
\leq \frac{1}{2} \rho(x,y) \, e^{2 L_f t},
$$
so that
$$
e^{-2 L_f t} |Tx(t) - Ty(t)| \leq \frac{1}{2} \rho(x,y), \qquad \forall t\in [0,T]
$$
and (*) follows.

Comment: May I please some more explicit explaination on $\int_0^t L_f \rho(x,y)\, e^{2L_f s}\, ds
\leq \frac{1}{2} \rho(x,y) \, e^{2 L_f t}$? Thanks!

Comment: May I please ask why we can do it by choosing L? I think it is an arbitary fixed number.

Comment: I have edited the answer to address the first question. For the second question, you can choose any $L > L_f$. In general you do not have contractivity of the operator if $L \leq L_f$.